# Validação JTextField

Tags: java, swing

Estou tentando validar o campo `txtServicoValor` que recebe um tipo `BigDecimal`, segue meu código, a validação está barrando tanto a forma correta dos dígitos como a incorreta, agradeço a ajuda.

```java
MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("###.###,#00.00");

JFormattedTextField campoTexto = new JFormattedTextField(mask);

mask.setValidCharacters("0123456789");

validos.install(campoTexto);

if(txtServico.getText().length() > 0
        && txtServicoValor.getText().length() > 0
        && (txtServicoValor.getText().replaceAll("\.", "").replace(",",".")).equals(campoTexto))
{
    servico.setServico(txtServico.getText());
    servico.setValorServico(new BigDecimal(txtServicoValor.getText().replaceAll("\.", "").replace(",",".")));
}
```

Comment: O que vem a ser a variável `validos`?

Comment: ouve um erro de digitação, o que deveria está no lugar de válidos seria o objeto mask.Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema é um erro muito bobo. Ele está aqui:

```java
(txtServicoValor.getText().replaceAll("\.", "").replace(",",".")).equals(campoTexto)
```

Isto daqui é uma `String`:

```java
(txtServicoValor.getText().replaceAll("\.", "").replace(",","."))
```

Isto daqui é `JFormattedTextField`:

```java
campoTexto
```

Uma `String` nunca vai ser igual a um `JFormattedTextField`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!Vou corrigir o código e testar.